# How to enable and disable colorbox JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if condition and disable colorbox and vice versa. Help me

```
if($(".usercert:checked").length > 0){
  //I need to enable colorbox
}else{
// I need to disable colorbox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if($(".usercert:checked").length > 0){
      //do something
    }else{
      $(classname).removeClass('cboxElement');
    }
```